# Visual Basic: Error message upon finding a set of conditions

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Range("J11").Value < 0 Then
    MsgBox "You have exceeded the maximum allowable pipe length for this section. Please review your selection before continuing. ", vbOKOnly, "Inoperable Pipe Length"
End If
Do While ActiveSheet.Range("J17,J7").Value = "Reducer"
   If ActiveSheet.Range("J18, J8").Value = "" Then
        For i = 7 To 17 Step 10
            Dim X As Range
            Set X = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer").Offset(1, 0).Address
            MsgBox "Please Select a reducer size in cell " & X, vbOKOnly, "No Reducer Selected"
        Next
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I am attempting to do the following:

I have cell in which is only required to be filled in when "Reducer" is selected from a listbox.

These cells are 10 rows apart exactly (Thus, attempting to step 10 every iteration). There will be many more iterations, which is why I want to try to do it through loops rather than listing each cell individually.

Upon the macro (attempting) to run, I get the error: Run time error '91': Object variable With block variable not set.

I apologize if I am missing something elementary, as I am just today attempting to figure out vBa.

EDIT:  The following line is giving me the error:

```
Set X = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer").Offset(1, 0).Address
```

Comment: which line raises the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line *does* look suspect, but not for the reason previously given.

```
Set X = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer").Offset(1, 0).Address
```

The reason I say this is a potential error, is because of what happens if `"Reducer"` is **not found**.  Do you know what happens?  This part of the statement evaluates to `Nothing`

```
Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer")
```

ANd you can't use `.Offset` (or any other method) on `Nothing`.

**ALSO** note that `.Address` returns a *string*, not a range object, so you can't assign it to an object variable like `X`.  Omit that part, and then use some simple if/then to control for the potential `Nothing`-ness:

```
If Not Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer") Is Nothing Then
    Set x = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer").Offset(1, 0)
End If
```

**Question for you**

Why are you using the range `.Find` method on only a single cell?  If in fact you are trying to find a value in a cell, the `Instr` function seems more appropriate to use.  Otherwise, I suspect you need to expand your range beyond `Cells(10,i)`.

```
If Instr(1, Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Value, "Reducer") <> 0 Then
    Set x = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Offset(1, 0)
End If
```

Comment: I added the snipped of code you suggested in place of what I had previously. For some reason the first line you suggested is throwing a fit - It throws a compile error, highlights IsNothing, and states "Sub of Function not defined". I attempted to change this statement slightly to see if maybe somehow syntax was off, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, I had my syntax backwards, Try revised answer above.  Also something funny about this is that you're using the `.Find` method on a single cell.  I suspect that is not actually what you want to do...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was entirely unaware of the `Instr` function existing. `.Find` seemed to make sense, and I never found anything on `Instr`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspect:

```
Set X = Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer").Offset(1, 0).Address
```

Sheets("Pipe Calcs") seems to be unqualified.  You are probably looking for:

```
Set X =  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pipe Calcs").Cells(10, i).Find("Reducer").Offset(1, 0).Address
```

You didn't seem to specifiy which Workbook you want to use Sheets from.  Give that a try.

Comment: My apologies, I did fail to mention that it is, in fact, stopping execution at the line you pointed out.

I added the suggested line, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: @user3780727: Yes, sorry, I realized it wasn't the issue a little while after I posted.  Deleted it, but you obviously saw it already.  Figured I'd undelete it now since you commented on it already and it may help people in the future.